# An explanation of magic in Call of Cthulhu

Tags: spells, magic, call-of-cthulhu

I've been searching for an explanation on how magic works in CoC but  I haven't found a big recap on how to use it, what it is and how an investigator can use it.

If someone had a link for me or an explication, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Do you have a copy of the rulebook? They are really good with mechanical and background information for how magic works.

Comment: This isn't a question, this is asking people to copy and paste the rules for you.

Comment: A **recap** isn't a step-by-step copy-and-paste of the rulebook. There are many reasons to want an overview that have nothing to do with laziness or piracy (curiosity chief among them).

Comment: I don't want a copy of the rules, i want an to understand HOW in the workd of CoC magic is really working. I don't have any interest on how rolls working in there. But no, i don't have a copy of the rulebook, if you tell me there is an explanation here a will look up.

Comment: @AntoineRenault We expect question-askers to do a little research before posting a question here, and when it comes to asking questions about specific aspects of a setting and system, reading the relevant rulebook is usually the first stop. If you have specific questions about how to interpret what your research turns up, we can help with that - but if you're simply unwilling to read the relevant resource yourself, this question is likely to be closed.

Comment: Fine by me, thanks for your time. I will come back to the site if I had any questions more precise.

Answer (score 6):

There isn't much to know. Magic in *Call of Cthulhu* is not something that the player characters deal with much, if at all, since [using magic usually means the end of the character](http://www.rpg.net/reviews/archive/13/13975.phtml):

> Some characters will learn little bits of ritual magic during their time investigating the dark places of Earth. These spells tend to be very narrow, fairly powerful, and usually maddening to cast. If being an investigator is hard on the mind, becoming a sorcerer is downright suicidal at times. Academically inclined characters who decide to learn a few spells will have to balance their Sanity against the usefulness and power offered to them by magic.

Spells don't always and immediately cause the PC to be unplayable, but they *likely* do, so it's not a part of the game that players are expected to use much, if ever. How an investigator uses magic is usually highly dependent on how they discovered such a mind-breaking secret of the universe, and is therefore much more up to the Keeper's discretion than is usual for games with magic.

As for mechanical details, how magic operates (aside from destroying the caster's mind), is quite similar to how it works in other games in the *Basic RolePlaying* family: you begin casting the spell, you roll your magic skill (if applicable), you subtract the Magic Points from your pool, and the spell does what it says it does. The rest of a typical magic system (e.g., how you learn spells, how many you know, how you recharge Magic Points, etc.) are not really relevant, because investigators who cast spells are extremely rare, and rarely survive the experience. They certainly don't make a habit of doing it, let alone build up a repertoire of spells that they throw around casually as in fantasy variants of BRP.